# Migrating an application to a service mode [java/groovy]

Tags: java, service, groovy, communication

I've got an application written in groovy. It takes some cmd args and returns previously formatted response. As system grew, it appeared that it is required to run this app extremely frequently (like 80 times in 5 mins) which leads to certain performance issues. In particular it creates all its objects over and over again which leads to filling up to 60MB RAM in one run (can be easily calculated how severely ROM/swap is used).

I want to migrate it to a service running mode which will simply take certain params and return formatted output. But:

1. App is always triggered by a bat/sh script (this can't be changed)
2. Both script and app are on the same host server

So, I'm wondering how it would be better to perform the communication of a script and a service?

P.S.: Sorry that I didn't mention, it's a standalone app, it will never use a server or anything like that as it appears to be redundant. Solution should be as simple as possible and extremely lightweight.

Example: The simplest thing I can think of by now is never to migrate it (I know it's contradictory ;)) and simply introduce a DB where all thee result will be stored and an app will have it's own schedule of when to trigger. Whenever it is triggered with any params, it should simply search the latest result in DB and return it. Easy,  light, fast, and working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For enterprise environments I would suggest a JavaEE application with EJB running in an application server. For your requirements this might be an overkill. A simple solution can be:

- Service: Implement a RMI server with a local RMI registry. Calculations will be done here.
- Script: Connect to the RMI server, invoke a method at the RMI server and display the result.

---

**RMI Server**

```
public class RmiServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RmiInterface
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RmiServer() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();
    }

    public String random() throws RemoteException
    {
        return "Helo World! "+(new Random()).nextInt(100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException
    {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        Naming.rebind("myServer", new RmiServer());
    }
}
```

**RMI Client**

```
RmiInterface server = (RmiInterface)Naming.lookup("//127.0.0.1/myServer");
System.out.println(server.random());
```

**RMI Interface**

```
public interface RmiInterface extends Remote
{
    public String random() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: Please see edited P.S.. Your suggestion is good, thank you, but simple setDaemon and socket building does the same and much easier.

Comment: That depends on your method and return objects and also the number of different methods to invoke. With RMI you can directly call the method on the remote object, with sockets you may be faced to implement a protocol.

Comment: @Thor, The idea is that I never said that it returns objects. It returns formatted text.

Comment: @den-javamaniac Ok, But even this is a `java.lang.String` or `List<String>` ;-) Give it a try, I extended my answer with a working example of RMI.

Comment: @Thor. ok, lets move on: how do you connect to an RMI from a script? As I wrote earlier, App is always triggered by a bat/sh script (this can't be changed), so to do it, I need a separate app to be run. So it's two apps running on a LOCAL HOST establishing RMI. Can't see why would I give up a socket idea. :D

Comment: @den-javamaniac Why not starting a java app with the script? If I understand it correct, you cannot change the fact, that the client must be started with a bat/sh, but you can change the content of the script. Sockets sure will work, but IMO the RMI solution is easier to implement, because all network related stuff is done by the framework.

Comment: @Thor, That's not true, about simplicity. It only makes the app fat. Just look, you'll have to 1) add the framework, 2) separate app on client and server 3) make server a daemon 4)trigger client frequently trough script. If you do it through sockets, it's only the step 3 here, as step 4 can be easily done through shell. I'd say that your solution is easy only if you know RMI and have a vague understanding of shell and threads.

Comment: @den-javamaniac 1) it's part of JavaSE6, you also need a Socket class 2) That's done by an interface and I think this will led to a better architecture 3)4) As you said, it's also required by a socket solution. I also started with Socket many years ago, the next step was RMI and this led for more complex architectures to EJB. ... But please let's stop this discussion ;-)

Comment: @Thor, well... on the other hand I choose sockets because have no idea how to eat RMIs. I'll try then, if it's effective, it'll suite me. Thanx. :)